# Variable not expanding in Double quotes for bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a bash script where i'm trying to call a curl which is having a variable value as input. When trying to execute the bash script the variable value is not getting expanded in double quotes.

Expected curl in script after variable expansion should be as following:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s -vvvv http://hmvddrsvr:8044/query/service -u iamusr:pssd -d 'statement=DELETE FROM `test_bucket` WHERE type = "Metadata" AND market = "ES" AND status = "active" AND meta(test_bucket).id="fgsd34sff334" '
```

Getting executed as follows when observed in debug mode:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s -vvvv http://hmvddrsvr:8044/query/service -u iamusr:pssd -d 'statement=DELETE FROM `test_bucket` WHERE type = "Metadata" AND market = "ES" AND status = "active" AND meta(test_bucket).id=\""$idp_sub"\" '
```

My bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

idp_sub=""


for idp_sub in $(cat /opt/SP/jboss/home/mayur/es_idp_sub.txt)

do

/usr/bin/curl -s -vvvv http://hmvddrsvr:8044/query/service -u iamusr:pssd -d 'statement=DELETE FROM `test_bucket` WHERE type = "Metadata" AND market = "ES" AND status = "active" AND meta(test_bucket).id=\""$idp_sub"\" ' -o  /opt/SP/jboss/home/mayur/es_delete_response.txt


done
```

How does do i expand the variable value within double quotes as shown above in expected output ?

Comment: Don't use string interpolation to construct a SQL query. Use a language with a proper SQL library to create parameterized queries.

Comment: At the very least, use the new language's library for constructing URLs to make sure your query is properly URL-escaped, aside from ensure the resulting query is valid and safe SQL.

Comment: There's nothing here that needs to be URL-escaped; the only non-constant part is within the `-d` argument, which is to be POSTed as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1):

Your double-quoted string is inside single quotes, where it won't be expanded.

Compare:

```
foo=bar
echo 'foo=\""$foo\"'
echo 'foo="'"$foo"'"'
```

In the second example, we end the single quotes, and double-quote `$foo`, then start new single quotes for the final `'`.

It's probably easier to read if we expand using `printf` instead:

```
printf 'foo=%s\n' "$foo"
```

That's something you might want to run as a process substitution.

## BUT...

This is a **wrong** and **dangerous** way to construct an SQL query (and the web server is also poor, if it forwards arbitrary queries - I hope it has no write permissions to the data).  Read about "**SQL command injection**" and come back to this code when you understand the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inside single quotes will be expanded by bash, including any double-quotes, and variable names. The good news is you can end your single-quoted section and immediately start a double-quoted section to introduce the variable, and it will all be concatenated into a single argument for the application (curl). Try:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s -vvvv http://hmvddrsvr:8044/query/service -u iamusr:pssd -d 'statement=DELETE FROM `test_bucket` WHERE type = "Metadata" AND market = "ES" AND status = "active" AND meta(test_bucket).id=\"'"$idp_sub"'\" ' -o  /opt/SP/jboss/home/mayur/es_delete_response.txt
```

You can make your code strongly injection-proof by rejecting any string containing a double-quote, but you might reject some strings that have been legitimately escaped.

If you can use the q syntax to quote the string, you can make it more injection-proof, but I guess the attacker just has to inject `]"`:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s -vvvv http://hmvddrsvr:8044/query/service -u iamusr:pssd -d 'statement=DELETE FROM `test_bucket` WHERE type = "Metadata" AND market = "ES" AND status = "active" AND meta(test_bucket).id=q\"['"$idp_sub"]'\" ' -o  /opt/SP/jboss/home/mayur/es_delete_response.txt
```

You could then search for and reject the pattern string `]"` as your anti-injection, which will allow a much wider class of legitimate strings. You would have to tell the users that you have applied q[] quoting to their input, so they don't have to.

Comment: Please don't encourage vulnerability to SQL injection.

Comment: @chepner fair point, and worth making, but it is going to depend on context whether this really is a vulnerability. I assume you are going to suggest some such tools?

Comment: I made a suggestion in a comment to the question. Anything more specific for a question with such a fundamentally flawed premise just amounts to an opinion.

Comment: A pretty basic way to avoid injections is to reject variable values that include quotes. Of course it is possible to escape the quotes properly in modern sql, I believe. Hmm, it appears to be as simple as: `q'[The 'end' of the day]'`